# MS Access .accdb file opens for other but gives me "unrecognized database format"

Tags: ms-access

I have a client who works in Access 2007 on an db stored as an .accdb file.  Whenever I receive a copy of this file and open in Access 2010 I get "unrecognized database format".  Attempting to compact and repair gives that same error.

However I was present today when another colleague working with Access 2010 received the same emailed .accdb file that I was copied on and successfully opened the database without error.  Forms, tables, queries all loaded for him without issue.

Anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that AVG antivirus was corrupting my emails as it scanned them.  When I disabled email scanning and rebooted the issue was resolved.  After I made this post I had a hint when attached JPEGs started showing up with errors.

Comment: There is no need for any AV program to scan Access files, as the threat of propagation of malware in them is imaginary. It has always been this way, but the AV sellers won't tell you that. Every AV suite should have scanning of Access files TURNED OFF by default (not just the ones like Symantec that have a tendency to corrupt the files!).

Comment: Can AV scanners not be turned off for email contacts in your address book? Otherwise I disagree with @David-W-Fenton if you receive any attachment from an unknown individual you probably want to scan it for viruses.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be having the converters for older version. These need to be installed. Try going through the Office fix/repair option and make sure the converters are selected during the process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  As mentioned above I went through the  compact and repair process but it gives that same error and it doesn't offer any converters.  Are you talking about a different process?  Where would I locate the tools?  Thanks!

Comment: Rasika is referring to the **Office install** fix/repair process, not the in-Access **database** Compact/Repair process.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. Thanks Roland.